# Mailchimp test email - footer template

Tags: mailchimp

When I send a test email using Mailchimp I am seeing the template format for the footer instead of my business' contact details. Is this correct? I've Googled a bit, and can't seem to find an answer.

Here is what I see, in the **test email**:

> Copyright © 2014 *|LIST:COMPANY|*, All rights reserved.
>   *|LIST:DESCRIPTION|*
>
> Our mailing address is:
>   *|HTML:LIST_ADDRESS_HTML|*
>
> unsubscribe from this list    update subscription preferences

This is the message I see from Mailchimp:

> We'll automatically add your contact info into the footer block.
>   Contact information is required in all campaigns to comply with the
>   CAN-SPAM Act and international spam law.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, I figured this out. You need to send a test email from the campaign area, rather than the template area to see the correct footer formatting.